# How to assign numeric labels to all elements in a list/series/array based on numbers from a different list?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have two lists that contains two series of numbers, such as:

```
A = [1.0, 2.9, 3.4, 4.2, 5.5....100.3]
B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.2]
```

I would like to create another list of labels based on whether the elements in list B falls in an (any) interval from list A. Something like this:

```
C = [group_1, group_1, group_1, group_1, group_2, group_2, group_3]
```

i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5 all fall in the interval of 1.0 - 2.9 from list A, hence group_1; 3.0, 3.1 both fall in the interval of 2.9 - 3.4, hence group_2; and 5.2 falls in the interval of 4.2 - 5.5, hence group_3, etc..

It doesn't matter which interval from list A does the number from list B fall in, the point is to group/label all elements in list B in a consecutive manner.

The orginal data is large so it would be impossible to manually assign labels/groups to elements in list B. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the numbers in both `A` and `B` sorted?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, the numbers in both lists are sorted in the same order (ascending or descending).

Comment: What output do you want if a number isn't within one of the intervals in A?

Comment: @Nick It has to and will be in one of the intervals in A. This is guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for all your input, I have never used those functions and I will test out all the solutions and come back pick the best answer.

Comment: Given `A` is sorted, you can just do: `np.searchsorted(A,B) -> array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4])`

Comment: @QuangHoang Wow! This is pretty neat, thank you. I've learned so much on this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, assuming `A` is sorted, you can use binary search, which already comes with the python standard library in the (rather clunky) module `bisect`:

```
>>> A = [1.0, 2.9, 3.4, 4.2, 5.5]
>>> B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.2]
>>> [bisect.bisect_left(A, b) for b in B]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

This takes `O(N * logN)` time.

Note, take care to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) and how `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` behave when a value in `B` is equal to a value in `A`, and how items that wouldn't fall anywhere behave.

Comment: Assuming the lists are sorted, it seems to me it can be done in O(Na+Nb)?

Comment: @Julien I only assumed `A` is sorted, but I would probably just do this anyway because it's good enough and `bisect` is sitting right there.  But yeah, you could do better if both are sorted I believe.

Comment: All the solutions worked but I picked this one for being the simplest and the lists are indeed sorted. Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this for `O(n)` solution (assuming both lists are sorted and one number must be in one of the intervals in `A`):

```py
A = [1.0, 2.9, 3.4, 4.2, 5.5, 100.3]
B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.2]

grp = 0
i1, i2 = iter(A), iter(B)
a, b = next(i1), next(i2)

out = []
while True:
    try:
        if a < b:
            a = next(i1)
            grp += 1
        else:
            out.append(grp)
            b = next(i2)
    except StopIteration:
        break

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a tiny mutable "key function" would fit nicely (especially if requirements may change, or if you need to use this pattern elsewhere):

```py
import itertools

class ThresholdIndexer:
    """Callable that returns the index of the last threshold <= arg.

    Preconditions:
      - thresholds is sorted and not empty.
      - For all calls, `thresholds[0] <= call[i].arg <= thresholds[-1]`.
      - For all calls, `call[i - 1].arg <= call[i].arg`.
    """

    def __init__(self, thresholds):
        self.thresholds = thresholds
        self.i = 0

    def __call__(self, arg):
        while not (self.thresholds[self.i] <= arg <= self.thresholds[self.i + 1]):
            self.i += 1
        return self.i 

A = [1.0, 2.9, 3.4, 4.2, 5.5, 100.3]
B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.2]

for group_key, group_items in itertools.groupby(B, key=ThresholdIndexer(A)):
    print(f'{group_key}: {", ".join(str(i) for i in group_items)}')

"""Output:
0: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5
1: 3.0, 3.1
3: 5.2
"""
```

This approach is O(N<sub>A</sub> + N<sub>B</sub>).

You can remove these preconditions by binary-searching for the correct index in `__call__`, rather than assuming some latter index will "definitely" be correct. However, the complexity would bump up to O(N<sub>B</sub> × log N<sub>A</sub>).

Answer (score 3):

You can answer it in `O(len(B))` according to this code:

```
C= [0]*len(B)
i, j = 0, 0

while i < len(B):
    if (B[i] > A[j] and B[i] < A[j+1]):
        C[i] = j
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import numpy as np


A = [1.0, 2.9, 3.4, 4.2, 5.5, 100.3]
B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 5.2]
A_arr = np.array(A)
B_arr = np.array(B)
C = [np.searchsorted(A_arr, b) for b in B_arr]
print(C)
>>>
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: You can do `np.searchsorted(A,B)` directly.